# wp-admin throwing 500 errors after update to 4.2.1

Tags: wp-admin, upgrade

Site owner updated her multisite yesterday via the dashboard. The site itself is still running, but the network and primary site dashboard both return a 500 error. However, the wp-admin for two subdomain sites can be accessed just fine.

The related PHP errors showing up are these:

> [Mon Apr 27 23:36:21 2015] [warn] [client x.x.x.x] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds
>
> [Mon Apr 27 23:36:21 2015] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Premature end of script headers: update-core.php

Anyone seen this or have any idea?

Comment: I should mention that I have tried disabling all plugins and changing the twentyfifteen but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Another update: after rolling the site back to a 4.1.4, everything works again. Ran another automatic update from there and it broke again.

Comment: Isn't your issue solved - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-admin-returning-500-errors-after-update-to-421 ?

Answer (score 1):

based on https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-admin-returning-500-errors-after-update-to-421, seems like it was related to the conversions of tables to utf8mb format done in 4.2 which timeout when there are many comment.

Possible solutions: make the DB upgrade on some staging server in which all timeouts are off, or increase the timeout on the production server until it works.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the .htaccess in wordpress root
should bring site back up
reset permalinks
admin - settings - permalinks. If you don't see the htaccess file it is likely hidden you have to select show hidden files in whatever method you use to view files

Comment: Unfortunately, not a fix. I had already tried that but tried it again just because.